# How to insert large amount of data into MongoDB efficiently, instead of typing every single collection?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, rest, mongodb-atlas

I'm trying to build REST API with Node JS and MongoDB. I'm using MongoDB Atlas (https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas).
I need to insert large amount of data (200 of country names, city name and etc).
The schema for single country looks like :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const countrySchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true }
});

const Country = mongoose.model('Country',countrySchema);

module.exports = Country;
```

So, in order to insert country names I need to write each time every country name separately :
"
{
"name" : "countryName"
}
"

Is there any way of inserting all countries at the same time with following above Schema?

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Prepare a json file with all country names and use insertmany

Comment: Thanks for help, it worked.  Here link to the code which I used for this:https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/usage-examples/insertMany